# Diffence between a.salary,a["salary"] and a[["salary"]]

Tags: python, pandas

```
a=pd.read_csv("train.csv")
```

Suppose I am having some columns like `salary`,`name`,`age` and `id` in my data set.

What is the difference between `a.salary`, `a["salary"]`, and `a[["salary"]]`?

Comment: What do you get as results when you try these?

Comment: This is a `pandas` question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (edited).

Comment: you can use both `a.salary` or a['salary']. I  like a['salary'] more.  When you want to specify  one or more columns you can use `[[...]]`, which means that you are passing the list of columns you want.

Comment: Assume,suppose I am gonna predict the salary with respect to age.if I write code like below why do I get error.     X=df["age"] and y=df["salary"] in machine learning.

Comment: Actually I am new to stackoverflow.so forgive me if I made any mistake.

Answer (score 1):

By using type() function of python you get

```
type(a.salary) 
pandas.core.series.Series

type(a['salary'])
pandas.core.series.Series

type(a[['salary']])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

With that said, first 2 have the same functionality while the 3d differs

DataFrame and Series obj are very similar but some methods and attitudes differ.
The main difference is that Series is list alike while DataFrame is array alike.
DataFrame actually have a lot of series combined(each column is a Series).

Its wise to treat single columns as Series and not as DataFrame as they don't have exactly the same functionality.For example, you can't set a Series to a DataFrame.

This code:

```
a[['salary']] = df['example'].copy()
```

won't work as `a[['salary']]` is a treated as a DataFrame while `df['example']` is treated as a Series.

while:

```
a['salary'] = df['example'].copy()
```

will work, because you treat the column 'salary' as Series.